# How to use the Cake build system with GitHub Action

Tags: c#, build, github-actions, building-github-actions

I want to use the [Cake build system](https://github.com/cake-build/cake) for building my project and I want use it in GitHub action for helping [continuous integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) and more.

But I couldn't find any useful document to what are you doing. Is there one?

Is there any documentation or best practice about this?

I searched for it, but I did not find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some working I found some useful information about it in the [GitHub Cake project](https://github.com/cake-build/cake/issues/2609#issuecomment-602574451)

- you can find general information about the build system in
  *[Build System aliases](https://cakebuild.net/dsl/build-system/)*
- you can find specific information about GitHub Actions in *[GitHubActions(ICakeContext) method](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Build/BuildSystemAliases/6C2FCAF0)*
- you can find specific information about the GitHub Actions environment in *[GitHubActionsEnvironmentInfo Class](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Build.GitHubActions.Data/GitHubActionsEnvironmentInfo/)*
- and finally find specific actions in *[Cake for GitHub Actions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/cake-action)*